# Modal Overlay not closing by default, bugs when explicitly handled with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an overlay.

```
  <div class="overlay modal" id="11">
    <div class="background-overlay"></div>
      <div class="description">
        <div class="hidden-xs">
          <img src='img.jpg'/>
        </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p> Hand Wash Monitor </p>
        <p class='proj-title'> Android+Octave </p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Then used bootstrap to open this overlay.

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#11">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
  <h2>Android Programming</h2>
  <p> some text</p>
</div>
```

I wanted the overlay to be closed when anywhere on the background-overlay is clicked, so I created a jquery onclick listener.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.background-overlay').on('click',function(){

$('.overlay').hide();
// $('#your-modal-id').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
  });
});
```

As expected the above code opens my overlay when clicked on corresponding section, and closes when clicked on background.

However there is a small glitch, when I open the overlay I just need single click to open it. When I try to open it second time I need to double click on the section to open it.

The problem is because I'm using data-toggle to open, but jquery onclick to close it.

Whats the alternative way to do this so I just can use single click to open my overlay every time, and closes when clicked on background-overlay.

Here is how it looks, try opening and closing same modal repeatedly

https://pradeepsaiu.github.io/src/index.html

Comment: it works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vo1npqdx/669/

Comment: It's weird how it's working in the snippet you showed. This is how my code looks now https://pradeepsaiu.github.io/src/index.html

Comment: Try to `/* */` comment `background-overlay` click event and see what will happen without it ..if it work fine .. then try to comment each line on the click event to find the line cause this issue

Comment: disabling click even, wont let me close the overlay at all.

Comment: I should add modal-dialog, which handles the click on the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "modal-dialog" class helped me solve this, Just wrapped my content of modal inside this class to solve the problem.

```
 <div class="overlay modal" id="11">
**<div class = "modal-dialog">**
    <div class="background-overlay"></div>
      <div class="description">
         <div class="hidden-xs">
         <img src='img.jpg'/>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
          <p> Hand Wash Monitor </p>
          <p class='proj-title'> Android+Octave </p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `script` to close modal you can use `data-backdrop="true"`

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#11" data-backdrop="static">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
  <h2>Android Programming</h2>
  <p> some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: data-backdrop is only to show or hide the background, It had nothing to do with controlling the closing. data-keyboard was something relevant but didn't seem to work.

Comment: If you pass `data-backdrop="static"` then modal won't hide on backdrop click. for reference you can check http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Comment: Yes, my bad you are correct. In my case I want it to be closed so setting it true - would give me dark overlay
false - no overlay (transparent). But it is not giving me close functionality by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = $('#1');
  if  (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){
     $('#1').modal('hide');
  }
)};
```

Comment: Hey that might work, but I was wondering how it works based on bootstrap toggle.